# Rate booster for MS Graph API for Onenote

Tags: onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-api

Do we have rate booster for MS Graph API. Any paid service or other option which allows a particular app to access large number of request for a particular user to access Onenote content using MS Graph API.

Currently I get throttling exception very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running into throttling during development, or while running through a customer scenario?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/01/12/onenote-api-throttling-and-how-to-avoid-it/

> ...if you're running into throttling (429's) during development, you
>   can simply change your user or your app (this does require giving
>   permissions again) and keep coding/testing against the API.

Comment: Currently during development I am running into this. But I wanted to make sure in future this scenario doesn't happen while running through a customer scenario.
Is there anything that we can do before hand

Comment: If you follow the recommendations in the blog post above, you shouldn't run into it. If you still do land into throttling in a real customer scenario, you can report it to us @OneNoteDev in twitter or via email onapisupport(at)microsoft.com.